Labelling feature with count of values from another layer in QGIS
I have a layer A with 900+ features. There are two relative attributes: cpl (text) and number (integer).
The attribute cpl has 50 variations and the attribute number has 3. Each feature is unique but shares common values for these two attributes.
For example:



id
cpl
number




1
A
2


2
A
3


3
C
4


4
C
4


5
C
4


6
A
3


7
A
3


8
A
3


9
B
3


10
B
4


11
A
4


12
A
3


13
A
2


14
B
3


15
B
4


16
D
2


17
D
2


18
D
2


19
E
4


20
E
2



In layer B I have 50 features, one for each of the variations of cpl. This is a dissolved layer from Layer A. I want to label each of the 50 features so that the label expresses the type and count of the number for each of the cpl.
So for instance layer B label for cpl A would read:
2 (2),
3 (5),
4 (1)
Because layer A has 8 features with cpl 'A', with 2 counts of number '2', 5 counts of number '3' and 1 count of number '4'
I have used get_feature and attribute before in other labels, but I get stuck because get_feature only returns the first instance. I have also made a virtual layer from layer A containing only the values for cpl and the count of numbers, for each variation. This virtual layer then looks like so:



id
cpl
number
count




1
A
2
2


2
A
3
5


3
A
4
1


4
B
3
2


5
B
4
2


6
C
4
3


7
D
2
3


8
E
2
1


9
E
4
1



But I still can't get the label right using get_feature. Any suggestions?
